# Change Default Install Directory of Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, development-environment

I would like to install Visual Studio 2008 on a PC with an existing VS2005 install.  Due to the lack of space on my C: drive, I would like to install VS2008 on my D: drive.  Is this possible?

#### Note:

I have reinstalled all trivial applications on my D: drive, and have cleared as much space as possible on the C: drive. Due to the fact that my development machine is locked down, I cannot change the default partition size or rebuild the machine.

I am aware that this is not strictly a programming question, but as it does relate to the development environment, I thought I would ask it.

Comment: Why are you working in an environment that you don't have full control over your development machine?

Comment: It's called real life; I work for a large enterprise that is generally good to work for, but occasionally throws these obstacles at you.  Every job I have worked for has something that works against the developer doing his or her job; this is the issue with my current job.

Comment: That's a pretty common scenario when you work for someone else.

Comment: Reminds me why I refused to work for a large company. I'm with Malfist regarding this topic. Is there really no way to get these things changed by your IT department? I mean, you're allowed to install Visual Studio on your own, so you can't increase the partition size?

Comment: More to the point, if IT policies prevent you from doing your work, make sure they know about it. Maybe even ask _them_ to do the installs for which you have no space left on C:\. Share the pain, and maybe they'll cure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a custom install, you have the opportunity to specify the target directory, although some space on the system drive will still be required.

Comment: I believe this space is for stuff that goes in Program Files\Common Files.  If you get your Program Files folder moved, it might help (of course, that would also require you to ask IT...).